# Adding object to a JPanel from external class

Tags: java, swing

Hi I am trying to add an object for example a JLabel from a main class to a secondary class that inherits the attributes of a JPanel.I have created a basic example that shows what I was trying to do but it dosen't work.Here is my code:

```
public class main extends JFrame{


public main(){
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    panel nou = new panel(new JLabel("a mers"));
}
public static void main (String[] args){
    new main();
}
```

}

```
public class panel extends JPanel{

    public panel(JLabel nou){
        this.add(nou);
    }
}
```

My original code has to add some images from an external class and I tried the same aproach but it dosen't work.How can I achive this?

EDIT:This is just an example I need to add this component from an external class

Comment: 1) Don't extend the panel or frame, simply keep a reference to one of each. 2) Always call `pack()` on the top-level container (TLC) 3) Call `setVisible` on the TLC last. 4) Swing GUIs should be created and changed on the EDT. 5) There are more 'wrong' lines in the code shown, than are correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Container#add(Component)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29).  You can use it the same way within the constructor as you can outside of it (without the this).

```
nou.add(new JLabel("trees"));
```

Comment: this is just an example I need to add the component from an external class

Comment: Can you possibly reword your question?  I'm not sure if you're asking how to add components to the JPanel outside of its constructor, or if you're asking how to add to the JFrame outside of its constructor, or if you're asking something else altogether.

Comment: I have two clases in my original project one of them extends a JPanel and I need to add from the other class an JLabel into that JPanel

Comment: In that case, my answer is doing just that.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the `JPanel` instance, but not adding to the `JFrame`.

Also please use the convention of Capital Camel Case for class names.